# Tabela multiplicando os dados

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados

Bom ja estou com esse problema a algum tempo e gostaria da ajuda de vcs , 
tenho 3 tabelas que seria venda , vendaproduto , vendaservico . e eu insiro os itens da tabela venda nas outras duas tabelas com o seguinte codigo :

```
       mysql_query("INSERT INTO vendaproduto (id_venda, produtos)
SELECT  venda.id_venda, venda.produtos
FROM venda")or die(mysql_error());

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO vendaservico ( id_venda, servicos)
SELECT  venda.id_venda, venda.servicos
FROM venda")or die(mysql_error());
```

assim que eu insiro a primeira linha fica tudo ok , mais quando eu insiro a segunda linha , nas duas tabelas (vendaproduto, vendaservico) ja aumenta dobra o numero de linhas e a cada registro novo o numero de linha dobra , alguem pode me da uma ajudinha nisso ?

**codigo todo :**

```
<?php
ini_set('default_charset','UTF-8');

if(isset($_POST['send'])){
    $venda = $_POST['num_venda'];
    $data = $_POST['data_venda'];
    $placa = $_POST['placa'];
    $km = $_POST['km'];
    $produtos = $_POST['produtos'];
    $servicos = $_POST['servicos'];


    include ('banco.php');


    mysql_query("INSERT INTO venda(id_venda, num_venda, data_venda, placa, km, produtos, servicos)
            values(
                NULL,
                '{$venda}',
                '{$data}',
                '{$placa}',
                '{$km}',
                '{$produtos}',
                '{$servicos}'

                            )
            ");
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO vendaproduto (id_venda, produtos)
SELECT  venda.id_venda, venda.produtos
FROM venda")or die(mysql_error());



    mysql_query("INSERT INTO vendaservico ( id_venda, servicos)
SELECT  venda.id_venda, venda.servicos
FROM venda")or die(mysql_error());

}

header("location:lista.php");
?>
```

**Tabelas :**

[image: Tabela venda]

[image: Tabela vendaproduto]

[image: Tabela vendaservico]

Comment: Você está inserindo todos os registros da tabela venda toda hora. Tem que adicionar apenas o último registro.

Comment: vllw pela força , eu tentei do seu jeito e deu o seguinte erro **"Invalid use of group function"**

Comment: Tenta assim: "INSERT INTO vendaproduto (id_venda, produtos)
SELECT  venda.id_venda, venda.produtos
FROM venda LIMIT 1 ORDER BY venda.id_venda DESC "

Comment: me retorno o seguinte erro **"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER BY venda.id_venda DESC' at line 1"**

Comment: POE O "LIMIT 1" depois do "DESC", não lembro muito bem da sintaxe MySQL

Comment: Muito obrigado cara era exatamente isso que eu precisava deu certinho vlw em ;)

Comment: Que bom! Coloquei como resposta pra você marcar como resolvido!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está inserindo todos os registros da tabela venda toda hora. Tem que adicionar apenas o último registro.

Tenta assim:

```
INSERT INTO vendaproduto (id_venda, produtos) SELECT venda.id_venda, venda.produtos FROM venda  ORDER BY venda.id_venda DESC LIMIT 1
```